# Metatags are not indexing for some websites

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch to crawl some websites and index the data to Elastic Search by the help of a custom plugin (myplugin).

I need information stored in meta tags from the crawled sites. So in order to achieve this I just added properties in nutch-site.xml as follows :

```
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-httpclient|myplugin|urlfilter-regex|parse-(tika|html|js|css|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|metadata)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|indexer-elastic</value>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>metatags.names</name>
        <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>index.parse.md</name>
        <value>keywords,description</value>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>index.content.md</name>
        <value>keywords,description</value>
  </property>
```

It works fine with some sites, but didn't worked with site like [this](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/database-benchmarking-092016.html)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the answer and hints provided by [Julien nioche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432844/julien-nioche) you can change your ***parser-filter plugin*** to something like this to lowercase all meta names inside which will solve the issue for now.

```
        Metadata newMeta=new Metadata();
        Metadata oldMeta=parse.getData().getParseMeta();
        String metaValue;
        for(String metaName:oldMeta.names()){
          metaValue=oldMeta.get(metaName);
          newMeta.add(metaName.toLowerCase(),metaValue);
        }

        parseData = new ParseData(status, title, parse.getData().getOutlinks(), 
                                      parse.getData().getContentMeta(), newMeta);
        parseResult.put(content.getUrl(), new ParseText(text), parseData);
        return parseResult;
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

It could be because the names are in uppercase

```
<meta name="Description" content="...">
<meta name="Keywords" content="...">
```

Maybe try the case variants in your config.

BTW you can use './nutch indexchecker ...' to test the extraction and field generation on a given URL.

EDIT : https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/index-metadata/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/metadata/MetadataIndexer.java#L92 lowercases the keys we are looking for but the key names in the parse metadata might be in the original casing i.e. with an uppercase.

Until this is resolved, you could add some custom code to your own plugin to lowercase the keys or alternatively modify the MetadataIndexer so that it preserves the casing or change the logic so that it can handle variants in the case.

Comment: Already tried this, but didn't worked. This config perfectly worked with http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-09-23/nvidia-job-postings-suggest-an-nvidia-chip-return-to-apple-macs

Comment: maybe but "http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-09-23/nvidia-job-postings-suggest-an-nvidia-chip-return-to-apple-macs" uses 'description' and 'keywords' in lowercase.

Comment: do in 2 steps - first check that they get extracted with parsechecker then use indexchecker to check that the fields are correctly generated

Comment: metatags are listed while checking with parsechecker, but not getting indexed. (using Elastic Search)

Comment: @JulienNioche : Is that because property names in index.parse.md and index.content.md is lowercase ?

Comment: @AbhishekRamachandran what is the output of indexchecker on that URL?

Comment: @JulienNioche : this is the output I got :-     tstamp : Tue Sep 27 16:02:22 IST 2016
digest : 1b11137c23c6b7ca7a4aac81ce0ea806
host : www.oracle.com
id : https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/oracle-marketing-cloud-orchestration-canvas-092616.htm
title : Oracle Marketing Cloud Extends Leadership with Next Generation of Cross-Channel Orchestration Canvas
url : https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/oracle-marketing-cloud-orchestration-canvas-092616.htm
content : Press Release Oracle Marketing Cloud Extends Leadership with Next Generation of Cross-Channel Orches

Comment: @JulienNioche : I got the metadatas in parse checker as :-  
Parse Metadata: Keywords=NYSE:UA,Under Armour, Inc. CUSTOMDATE=2016-05-10 dc:title=Stephen Curry Earns Top League Honor for Second Straight Year (NYSE:UA) Content-Encoding=UTF-8 Content-Type-Hint=text/html; charset=UTF-8 metatag.keywords=NYSE:UA,Under Armour.

Comment: @AbhishekRamachandran thanks. See EDIT to my answer above. This is a bug or at least something that should be improved. Please have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH/ to check whether this has already been reported and if not please open a new issue.

Comment: @JulienNioche : So it is an issue with nutch. Is there any workaround for this ?